# How to Customize Animation in Blend?

Tags: wpf, animation, effects, blend

I'm developing a small application using Blend, basically what I have in my application are two list views, lets call them List View A and List View B.

List View A represent the files in my computer that I want to sent to the server and List View B represent the files that are in the server.

What I want to do is to create a transition effect that I will use when a file has finished it's upload process to the server, I want to fade out the file in List View A which I just uploaded, and fade in the same file in List View B, meaning that it is in the server.

I can create an animation that does exactly what I described using hard coded items in both List View controls, but I don't know how can I make the animation flexible, so it works when the items are added dynamically, in other words, how can I take a predefined animation and use it in the items that the user will add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create a DataTemplate for the items in the both lists, then you can attach a trigger to those DataTemplates for the animations you're talking about.

Hope that helps